# How to save with .push an array to read outside of .map(), with async?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, array.prototype.map

I have an array named `codigo` and I `.push` it some data inside of `.map()`.
When I put a `console.log(codigo);` inside the `map()` the result is correct, but when I put the console log outside of `.map()` the result is empty.

```
let pre = '';
let cod = [];
devPre.map(async (item)  => {
  pre = await models.pres.findOne({
    where: {
      id: item.pres_id,
    },
  });
  cod.push(pre.codPre);
  console.log(cod); // This return the correct values
});
console.log(cod); // This return [], this is my error
```

I need that the outside `console.log` returns with the correct values, like the  other `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Await a Promise.all over all values you're retrieving:

```
const allPromises = devPre.map((item)  => {
  return models.pres.findOne({
    where: {
      id: item.pres_id,
    },
  });
});
const pres = await Promise.all(allPromises);
const cod = pres.map(pre => pre.codPre);
```

Comment: sorry, until now i can prove it. It works, thank you @CertainPerformance